# How to add content to a shape?

Tags: orchardcms

I am trying to use a projection to display a custom content type ("Painting") as a list of shapes ("PaintingShape.cshtml") in Orchard 1.7.

This list of paintings has Parts like "Title" and "Body" (as you would expect) and custom fields like "Thumbnail Image" (a Media Library Image) and "Medium" (string).

How do I get these values into the .cshtml? Am I even going about this correctly? I have been using query layouts in the past but apparently is it not up to speed yet with the media library. (I have already filed a bug about missing Media tokens)

As most of the sites I work with have a library of images to display (websites for artists) managing and display images is very important. It look like media profile feature would be a boon to my work, but I have no idea how to implement this.

I feel that I am missing some fundamental concept on how Orchard works. As a designer who used to be able to program (sort of... read:ASP) I love how the admin and content interfaces work and the awesome ability to style the site but I'm losing it when it comes to making some bit of custom logic or template.

Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say placement.info 3 times fast and it happens!  No seriously though you don't necessarily need to create a shape alternate as the placement info will determine what to display.  Make sure you get the design tools module and enable shape tracing.  This will give you a ton of info on what is actually rendering.  The projection is rendering your items as "DisplayType=Summary" meaning that by default summary displays only show certain fields like title, body summary...  In order to get the other fields to render use the placement info examples from the Orchard site.  The best way to really grasp this is to take a look at the orchard/modules source.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to reinvent the wheel! After finally picking apart the placement.info files in the theme and the MediaLibrary module and can now get Orchard to jump through a hoop or two. Now all I have to figure out is how to put a link around the image that goes to the content item and not the image directly.

Comment: Hope its not too late Keith but you just need to create an alternate shape for the content item.  Shape Trace will actually create the shape for you in your theme.  From there you can wrap the content article with an anchor.